# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28/02/2016"

Tags: java, date

I am trying to parse the following date:
28/02/2016
using the following code:

```
             String cDate = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
             Date dates;
             dates = null;
             SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
             try {
                   dates = dateFormat.parse(cDate); 
                 }  
             catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Edit_Match_Final.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

However, I get the error: 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28/02/2016"

Comment: Look at the format you're passing into the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor. Now look at the format of the text you're passing into `parse`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the format specification string wrong, should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong format for parsing. Use this one: dd/MM/yyyy
instead of dd-MM-yyyy. Or you can use [JChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic) for automatic data parse. For example:

Chronic.parse("14/2/2001")
Chronic.parse("20 Jan 2010")